# Can't build an official example from Google

Tags: java, android, virtual-reality

I clone repository:
https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/

I try to run in Android Studio, did not change anything, but I getting errors:

```
Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-controllerclient/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-controller:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-controllerclient/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog

Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-simplepanowidget/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-videowidget:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-simplevideowidget/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(40, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-treasurehunt/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(39, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-audio:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-treasurehunt/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(43, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-common:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-videoplayer/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(42, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.60.1
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Vesbat/Documents/KODE/gvr-android-sdk/samples/sdk-videoplayer/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

Comment: I think you cloned the SDK and not a sample. The SDK has no value as an app, you have to find a sample using the VR sdk

Comment: @LunarWatcher, I used https://developers.google.com/vr/android/download
There is an sample + sdk in the repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Problem #1:*

They use since 25.5.2017 libs V 1.60.**1** but on global repo there current no 1.60.1 please see here: https://bintray.com/google/googlevr/sdk-audio#files/com/google/vr/sdk-audio

As a temporary solution you can switch to 1.60.**0** back

*Problem #2:*

When you did this, you will run into an incompatible Gradle plugin version (they use an old one)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.0-beta4'
```

change to this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.2'
```

Comment: Today they fixed https://bintray.com/google/googlevr/sdk-audio#files/com/google/vr/sdk-audio 1.60.1 should work now

Answer (score 2):

Replaced in each file build.gradle

```
Dependencies {
Compile 'com.google.vr: sdk-audio: 1. +'
Compile 'com.google.vr: sdk-base: 1. +'
}
```

Will be crashed after compilation, updated and the errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I got build error issue while compiling googles gvr android sdk code 
which get from https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk.
If you encounter build issue with it, please update your project

from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.0-beta4'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.9.3'
```

And

update your dependencies from 1.60.1 to 1.60.0

it will solve build issue.

Thanks,

Happy coding

Comment: Can you please tell us where you got this information please.

Comment: I follow Google document to get Android vr sdk

Comment: I build the code after I got from git​. I tried with different ways, finally I updated the above mentioned in my build, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

you can add the vr sdk dependencies using the aar file sdk-base-1.200.0.aar downloaded from the github repository. the file is located in the libraries folder. please refer this link if you are new to androidstudio
http://docs.onemobilesdk.aol.com/android-ad-sdk/adding-aar-files.html